# iPython notebook won't upgrade, always runs in v. 0.12

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, enthought

I've had some issues with iPython notebook since installing it for the first time. I already had installed iPython via pip install, but then I decided to install Canopy Express to get all the packages and a easy-to-use package manager. I am on a MBP with latest Yosemite installed.

When I run ipython notebook via.

```
ipython notebook --pylab inline
```

in a terminal, notebook starts up fine in Chrome.

But, then i check the version of iPython with

```
import IPython
IPython.__version__
```

it says 0.12 -- which is not the latest version at all. And does not allow me for instance to use **`%matplotlib inline`** (as magic is not added to that version)

If I try

```
pip install ipython --upgrade
```

i get :

```
"Requirement already up-to-date: ipython in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages"
```

When I check Canopy package manager, it says I have 2.3.1-2.

Any ideas?

My hunch is, that I might have several different dependencies/installations of python or ipython and that mess things up.
 Is there anyway I can completely remove everything and start afresh, or quickly rearrange my dependencies, such that they run via. Canopy?

PS. The first time I ran ipython notebook, I had just installed it using some guide, and I remember that it ran in something called jupyter?
 Still with in a browser, but not with normal IP[y]:Notebook logo. Is that strange?

edit:

```
which -a ipython gives 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/ipython
/usr/local/bin/ipython
/usr/local/bin/ipython
/usr/local/bin/ipython
/usr/local/bin/ipython
```

and

```
which -a python gives 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: There are a couple of things here: Please add `which -a ipython` and `which -a python` to the question. The problem is that you have multiple python versions scattered across your path. `jupyter notebook` will be the new `IPython notebook` - no need to worry. However there is not a stable version out yet.

Comment: I've added the edit, and also read up on "do's and dont's" when installing python. Looks like i'm guilty of a few of those. Are there anyway for me to remove all python (non-OSX related) and when do a clean install using Canopy?

Comment: You don't really have to clean those up. But you have to make sure that your `PATH` variable is consistent and prefers the correct interpreter. Installing `canopy` will probably set the `PATH` variable correctly. I guess it will work out of the box. If not you will have to adjust the `PATH` variable manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will self-answer this one.

1) Removed all non-OSx related python, following this: [How to uninstall Python 2.7 on a Mac OS X 10.6.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4)

2) Had a look in both .profile and .bash_profile. Deleted all past python dependencies (even had one to Anaconda). Easy using `open -a TextEdit .profile`

3) Reboot

4) Install Canopy Express. This is where I ran into new problems, as Canopy would not set itself as default python via the GUI. Fixed this by changing .profile and .bash_profile. See more [here](https://support.enthought.com/entries/23646538-Make-Canopy-User-Python-be-your-default-Python-i-e-on-the-PATH-).

5) Ran `ipython notebook %pylab --inline` in terminal, and now I have updated iPython!

Comment: Also see https://support.enthought.com/entries/22305234-IPython-Installed-version-in-the-Package-Manager-is-not-being-used-in-the-Canopy-GUI (re IPython version in Canopy)

Comment: And https://support.enthought.com/entries/23580651-Uninstalling-and-resetting-Canopy (re deleting detritus, now moot)