# IPython notebook installation error

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am having trouble getting my ipython to work after a regular python upgrade.
If I type:

```
ipython notebook --pylab inline
```

I get the following error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/ipython: No such file or directory
```

If I type:

```
which ipython
```

I get no response, just the command line prompt.
if I type:

```
which python
```

I get

```
/usr/bin/python
```

if I type:

```
ipython --version
```

I get the following error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/ipython: No such file or directory
```

When I inspect my system I see that my Ipython is installed in:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Ipython
```

**What should I do to make my ipython function again?**  I had to fix the links for pip and easy_install to get them to work after the python installation.  I just can't seem to get ipython working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pip install -U "ipython[notebook]"
```

You may need to prefix this with `sudo` for authorization purposes:

```
sudo pip install -U "ipython[notebook]"
```

Replace `pip` with `pip3` to install for Python 3.

Further install documentation is [here](http://ipython.org/install.html).

Comment: Jonathan this didn't work.  I got the following response:'Requirement already up-to-date: ipython[notebook] in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
'

Comment: Hmmm. Try an uninstall first. `pip uninstall ipython` (with possible `sudo`). Please also state what platform and platform version you're using. Mac, Windows, Linux, ...?

Comment: Good idea.  Mac OSX 10.10.2, python is 2.7.9 installed following steps 1-6 in [link](http://wolfpaulus.com/jounal/mac/installing_python_osx/)

Comment: using `sudo pip uninstall ipython` uninstalled ipython.  Re-installing and attempting to run `ipython notebook --pylab inline` produces `-bash: /usr/local/bin/ipython: No such file or directory`

Comment: It seems that it's trying execute ipython in an executable at `/usr/local/bin/ipython` that doesn't exist in the build.  Is there a way to change it to point to where the executable actually is?

Comment: Try typing this in bash: `export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`. Then try running IPython. I have a hunch your latest Python install is storing its packages in a new location.

Comment: I just tried the export command above.  Then tried running ipython.  same bash error `bash: /usr/local/bin/ipython: No such file or directory`

Comment: Is there a way to build ipython such that it loads into `/usr/bin/ipython` like my pip, easy_install, and python installation? Or use a command link `ln` to link where the executable actually is?

Comment: I finally figured out how to solve this: 

`sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/ipython /usr/bin/ipython`

linked my ipython to where it was hoping to find it.  stackoverflow won't allow me to enter my answer as an answer :)

Comment: I had created a symlink (to an anaconda distribution that I deleted) at /usr/local/bin/ipython. After deleting that link, I ran `pip uninstall ipython` followed by `pip install ipython`, and everything worked!

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend using Canopy (or Anaconda) as a package manager. Canopy, which I use, has its own terminal. Since I started using Canopy to manage my iPython environment, things have just been easier. Pip install/upgrades work like a charm every time, and I dont have to worry about mixing up python installations ect.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919761/ipython-notebook-wont-upgrade-always-runs-in-v-0-12) for more info.

PS. This should probably be a comment, but don't have enough rep yet to comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should be updated to be

```
pip install jupyter
```

From

[ImportError: No module named notebook.notebookapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401890/importerror-no-module-named-notebook-notebookapp)