# ImportError: No module named notebook.notebookapp

Tags: jupyter-notebook

What do you recommend guys for this error when I type in console `ipython notebook` and got

> ImportError: No module named notebook.notebookapp

?

I installed ipython notebook with pip and really I don't know what is going on.

Comment: I've tried every single answer here and none of them fix my `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'notebook.notebookapp'` error when trying to run `python manage.py shell_plus --notebook` even though the notebook (`jupyter notebook`) seems to run fine otherwise...

Answer (score 315, accepted):

For 4.0 and above You need to install the notebook app separately from https://github.com/jupyter/notebook

```
pip install jupyter
```

Comment: Correct. `pip install jupyter` is enough to fix the error and launch the notebook.

Comment: Or `pip3 install jupyter` if you're on a system where Python 3 is the default

Comment: If `ipyton notebook <notebook>` doesn't work for you, @meduz mentioned in a comment below that running `jupyter notebook <notebook` may work instead. That resolved the issue for me.

Comment: I have different python versions and `pip3.6 install jupyter` did the job

Comment: i get same error even after doing `pip install jupyter`

Answer (score 20):

`conda install jupyter` will install latest jupyter along with other required dependencies

The following packages will be downloaded:

```
package                    |            build
---------------------------|-----------------
mistune-0.7                |           py27_0         186 KB
jinja2-2.8                 |           py27_0         263 KB
jupyter_core-4.0.3         |           py27_0          25 KB
tornado-4.2.1              |           py27_0         515 KB
jupyter_client-4.0.0       |           py27_0          88 KB
nbformat-4.0.0             |           py27_0         112 KB
ipykernel-4.0.3            |           py27_0         111 KB
nbconvert-4.0.0            |           py27_0         266 KB
jupyter_console-4.0.0      |           py27_0          22 KB
notebook-4.0.1             |           py27_0         4.2 MB
qtconsole-4.0.0            |           py27_0         120 KB
ipywidgets-4.0.2           |           py27_0          93 KB
jupyter-1.0.0              |           py27_0           2 KB
------------------------------------------------------------
                                       Total:         6.0 MB
```

Comment: Anaconda installation users only.

Answer (score 11):

This two commands will fix most problems for you:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools pip
sudo pip install --upgrade "ipython[all]"
```

Answer (score 8):

I got the same problem when upgrading ipython. This is a bug linked to the latest `4` version, I recommend you switch back to the stable version `3.2.1`:

```
pip uninstall -y ipython
pip install ipython==3.2.1
```

- note: the `-y` option indicates "yes I want to uninstall" with no interaction
- note 2: possible duplicate in [ipython server can't launch: No module named notebook.notebookapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397421/ipython-server-cant-launch-no-module-named-notebook-notebookapp/31426690#31426690)

Comment: Works like a charm, but I additionally had to upgrade pip (sudo pip install -U pip) and a few packages via pip.

Comment: See other answer: `pip install jupyter`.

Comment: As @joeh said, it is recommended to upgrade to jupyter and to use the ``jupyter notebook`` command instead of ``ipython notebook`` one.

Comment: disclaimer: this answer was given in 2015 - please regard this as a solution which relevance is mainly historical :-)

Comment: Agree with above. Unless you are using an old Python version then this will likely cause many issues.

Answer (score 4):

this is what it worked for me:

```
pip install -U notebook
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using python version 2

> pip install jupyter

in case using python 3.x

> pip3 install jupyter

to be on the safe side also check that notebook module is installed or not

> pip install notebook

or

> pip3 install notebok

Answer (score 1):

Go to the path that will appear for you for example: `C:\Users\Soft\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py` and change `notebook.notebookapp` to just `notebook.app`. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pip install jupyter
```

It is worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Install Specific Version:

```
pip install jupyter
```

Upgrade  jupyter

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade jupyter
```

Getting Dependency Error in Window 10
Use code: easy_install instead of pip install

```
easy_install jupyter
```

Upgrade using easy install

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade  jupyter
```

On OSX System to install Module:
Use code: brew install instead of pip install

```
brew install jupyter
```

Without Using Pip :

```
 sudo apt-get install -y jupyter
```

On CentOS7 or Linux Fedora:

```
yum -y install jupyter
```

Or on Fedora try

```
sudo dnf install jupyter
```

Command if Homebrew screws up your path on macOS:

```
python -m pip install jupyter
```

For Python3 MacOs Homebrew screws

```
python3 -m pip install jupyter
```

Verify module from list MacOs

```
pip freeze | grep  jupyter
```

For Execute on Anaconda as your python package manager

```
 conda install -c anaconda jupyter
```

Answer (score 0):

from the env path C:\Users\awatim\envs\ds2\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py

Replacing notebook.notebookapp to just notebook.app is worked for me also

as above Abdelrahman Elaraby has mentioned same.

Answer (score 0):

NoModuleFoundError: notebook.notebookapp

It is because you imported the notebookapp module from the wrong folder, the notebookapp module you are trying to use is not in the notebook folder.

Go to the file location where the jupyter-notebook-script.py and open it in VS code. Now run this file and check the same error you occurred when trying to open the Jupyter Notebook from cmd prompt or from anything.

If the same error occurs then go to this file location C:\ProgramData\anaconda3 and search the { notebookapp } python now to go to the file location by cliking the left click on that file and you will get the option that is open file location now click on that.

You will directed to the location of that file. Now the most important, find out the folder in which this ( notebookapp ) file is stored.

In my case it was found in the nbclassic folder.

Open the file/script jupyter-notebook-script.py in vs code or any IDE and change the code like below. notebook changes to nbclassic

Before updating

---

```
import re
import sys

from notebook.notebookapp import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

---

After Updating

---

```
import re
import sys

from nbclassic.notebookapp import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

---

Change the code like that in my case it is found in nbclassic folder thats why i am importing from that.

```
from nbclassic.notebookapp import main
```

This will definitely work if you have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Just run

```
python manage.py shell_plus  --lab
```

and if you are running inside a docker container:

```
python manage.py shell_plus  --lab -- --allow-root --no-browser  --ServerApp.ip 0.0.0.0
```