# Uninstalling Python 2.7.9 without breaking vendor Python on a Mac OSX 10.9.5?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I'm a Mac newbie. I manually downloaded and installed Python 2.7.9 from the .pkg from python.org. I've come to realize that I should be installing software using package management like Macports or Homebrew as much as possible. My question is: how can I uninstall the Python version that I just installed? I'm hesitant to just delete anything out of my Applications folder for fear of breaking vendor Python.

I found this post [How to uninstall Python 2.7 on a Mac OS X 10.6.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4) but I'm not sure if I can just follow these same instructions for my purposes. Ideally I'd like to uninstall Python 2.7.9 and then reinstall using Macports or Homebrew. Thanks for any advice you can give!

Comment: it would not solve your issue but my experience using python on osx tells me that the best approach is using virtual environments (command virtualenv) to have a complete control on library versioning

Comment: It is a good question but probably off-topic here, try [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/). Although Python is primarily used for programming, this question could apply to any manually compiled software.

Comment: if it is **not** your system python  there is no problem removing it, is it in `/usr/local/bin`?