# Is there a way to remove all user installed packages/customizations etc?

Tags: python, macos, unix

When I started learning to program, I did not pay attention to where things were being installed, and did a lot of downloading, compiling and uninstalling without really knowing what I was doing. Mostly talking about python here, but there's a bit of Ruby too, and to be honest I don't know what else.

As a result, I have a great deal of cruft floating around my hard drive, and it's starting to cause problems.

So I really have 2 questions (on OSX):

1) Is there a good way to basically reset everything? Was thinking of creating a new user, and then just transferring the files I care about over, but I'm unclear if (or how to check) if there are system-level things that I need to fix. Completely reformatting would be a hassle, since there's an admin user created by my work that I can't touch.

2) Is there a good resource for best practices so I can avoid running into this problem in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For python, use a [virtual environment](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). This places you work in a seperate installation workplace for every different project. That is good practice using python. There are tons of good guidelines on how to do this. Of course there is a tool to make it (even) easier, called [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Using this, you simply say:

```
mkvirtualenv myproject
```

and from then on, you have a clean environment to install all kinds of dependencies into. If then later you start your computer again, you simply type `workon myproject`, and you continue with the same dependencies and install more or remove some, as you want. There is no contamination of the global environment.
Python IDE`s provide are also able to recognize virtual environments for your projects.

Once created a virtualenv, you use pip or easy_install to setup and manage the required packages, and it is miraculously easy to store your requirements in a small text file and to recreate the entire environment if it were to be deleted or corrupted in any way or when migrating your project to another system, using `pip freeze`, which tells you the modules residing in your environment. Storing the output in a file, i.e. `pip freeze > requirements.txt` allows you to rebuild the requirements for the project in another environment, using `pip install -r requirements.txt`. This is all standard practice.

Also a virtualenvwrapper allows you to set custom environment variables for that specific project, without messing up the global environment or other environments, but I doubt you need this.

So there won't be immediate need to get rid of old/existing installations. However if you still want to do that out of cleaning frenzy or so, and you never had any admin rights, you can probably do `pip freeze` to see what is in there, and remove what you don't need. 
What you suggest might work, start with a new user. Just move the project files and setup a virtual environment for each project.

For ruby i am not the expert but a similar kind of functionality is provided by rvm.

Comment: So if I do a virtual environment, it will basically start bare bones, not in the state the rest of my environment is currently at?

Comment: Still have a problem - I do have administrator access, and I've managed to fill up `/usr/local/bin` and other root-level things with random crap (including what looks like multiple python versions and installations, don't even remember that). When I say I "can't touch" work-installed admin profile, what I mean is "shouldn't touch".

Comment: I was able to use suggestions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4), except I just used `Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` rather than `...Python.framework/versions/2.7` for everything.  Seemed to do the trick.

Comment: multiple versions of python should not be a problem. use `virtualenv -p /path/to/pythoninterpreter` to create an env use specific python version. System wide, the command `python` is generally bound to one version, i.e. 2.7

Comment: the /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework thing is explained here: https://docs.python.org/2/using/mac.html