# Multiple installations of Python on Mac OS - can't install pip package

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I'm a beginner with both mac & python and kinda messed up python installations in order to install pip.

Here is the point where i am stuck right now:

I've 3 versions of python installed - (i) pre-installed by mac OS (ii) python 3.5.1 installation from python.org (iii) python 2.7 installation by home-brew

pip was not working, till I uninstalled the brew version by this command  `brew uninstall python`

now pip is showing command options but not able to install packages.

Here is the screenshot of errors I'm getting, after I gave command `pip install requests` :

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhUxZ.jpg)

I checked earlier links on stack overflow [here- bad python install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28613758/bad-python-install) & [here- uninstalling python2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4?lq=1&newreg=18c878fea33e44d9b60d03b3cb1cb08a) but can't resolve it.

guys i know i overdid while installing, but it's because pip was not getting installed. thanks a lot for helping me out !!

best

Comment: This isn't what you're asking about, but I highly recommend using `virtualenv` before installing packages with `pip`.

Comment: specify which version of pip to use for each version of pyhton ie. pip2 install. first install each version of pip for each version of python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this instead:

```
sudo pip install requests
```

Comment: dave thanks, it worked man. It worked for preinstalled python on mac, i checked in python shell by importing. As  suggested here, I 've to install pip again for python 3.5.

Comment: @lawsome great news. Please do check out `virtualenv`: http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to install request for your python 3.5 installation, try using pip3 install requests

using pip will use the OSX default installation instead of installing it for 3.5