# How to change the tk version of your Python installation?

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

I have just removed my old Python framework using [this procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3819829/3924118), and I have installed Python 3.4.3 for my architecture, which appears to be `i386` according to the following command `uname -p`, so I have downloaded and installed the following version [`Mac OS X 32-bit i386/PPC installer`](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-343/).

Now, I want to use `tkinter`, but it seems that it is using the Tcl/Tk version `8.4` instead of the lastest one `8.6`:

```
>>> tkinter.TclVersion
8.4
>>> tkinter.TkVersion
8.4
>>>
```

Now, I have cheked under the directory `/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/` which versions I have installed, but the result is:

```
8.5     8.6     Current
```

Which means that the Python distribution that I have just installed is using another version of `Tcl/Tk` from somewhere else.

Now, how do I change the `Tcl/tk` version that is being used?

Comment: Please read https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/.  You'll discover there that you can't change the Tk version without recompiling and relinking the _tkinter module in Python.  You probably should download and use the Python 3.4.3 64-bit/32-bit installer from python.org which is linked with Tk 8.5.

Comment: @NedDeily Yes, I thought it was not possibile to change according to some posts I have been reading. But what about the architecture? Do you think that version would still run?

Comment: `uname -p` is not a reliable indicator of whether your system is capable of running in 64-bit mode.  All Macs capable of running current OS X 10.10 are.

Answer (score -1):

You have to reinstall python.

> $ pip uninstall python3
>
> $ pip install python3