# `tkinter._test()` buttons are invisible when using pipenv

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-macos

I'm learning Tkinter right now and trying to work through my first issue, but finding Google hasn't been helpful.

I'm running this code on Mac OS X 10.15.1 (Catalina)

I'm using Python 3.7 and my code looks like so (lots of boilerplate per PEP8 standards):

```
"""
Experiments in tkinter
"""


import tkinter as tk


def main():
    """
    Main entrypoint
    """

    tk._test()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This outputs the following warning to the console:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.

It also displays a window with completely blank buttons:

[image: Output of <code>tkinter._test()</code>]

From my understanding these buttons should say "Click Me" and "Quit".

Also when I click on the top button it flashes black for a second like so:

[image: Result of clicking on first button]

After which the button is wider than before:

[image: Clicking twice]
[image: Clicking ten times]

I assume the Tk version error may be related to the output behavior. However I can't seem to find a way to update Tk. What should I do here?

### Update

After seeing @ShayneLoyd's answer (suggesting I needed an updated version of Python with an updated version of Tk) I began looking around some more and found [this post on the Apple Discussion Boards](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8066794) which suggests you can use homebrew to install a version of Python which link's homebrew's own installed version of Tk. I tried this and it failed, so I Google'd the issue and found [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53930597/updating-tcl-tk-version-of-homebrew-python3-on-macos) which seemed to suggest I can install 
[ActiveTcl](https://www.activestate.com/products/tcl/) and it will work.

I installed ActiveTcl from ActiveState and went back to my project. At first, I ran it like so:

```
$> cd ~/Source/experiments/python/tkinter
$> ./test.py
```

This actually ***worked***! I could read the buttons and it behaved like it should. Then I realized I was not using pipenv, so I did a quick test:

```
$> pipenv run ./test.py
```

Now I was back to the failure state. I updated my script to display the Tcl and Tk version and sure enough when I used pipenv it was loading Tcl/Tk 8.5.9 but when I didn't use pipenv it was loading 8.6.9

So how do I fix pipenv now?

Comment: I can not replicate your error. I don't understand why you need `tkinter._test()` to work because you never use it either

Comment: I want `tkinter._test()` to work because I'm using `tkinter` for the first time and this is like the `tkinter` version of "Hello, World". If this doesn't work, I need to fix my development environment. As for the "because you never use it", I don't know what you're saying -- I clearly ***do*** use it, right there in my code - and the window I have several screenshots of is the result.

Comment: Are you on OSX? I think this is a bug on OSX. If you resize the window, the text on the buttons will probably appear.

Comment: @BryanOakley This is OS X (10.15.1 Catalina, specifically). Although resizing the window did not fix the buttons.

Comment: Old habits die hard... it's actually macOS now, not OS X ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few hours messing with it I figured it out!

The `Pipfile` contained a reference to Python version 3.7

Therefore `pipenv install` was searching my machine for any 3.7 version of Python installed. The version it found was Homebrew's, which has Tk 8.5.9 statically linked.

By updating the `Pipfile` to require Python 3.8 my machine started pulling my system Python, which uses the dynamically linked Tk, which I had successfully updated to 8.6.9

Comment: it works like a charm !!, Just to be clear in the steps what I did was, 1) install python 3.8.2 from python.org, 2) install ActiveTcl as you mentioned before, 3) create the Pipenv env using "pipenv --python 3.8.2". if you create the env just with "pipenv install" it will use the old tcl/tk version.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone who's having the same issue and cannot switch Python version, you can easily bypass the "not showing text on buttons" problem by changing MacOs theme. System Preferences>General>Light Mode.

You should have in mind that you may encounter other problems.