# tkinter deprecation warning using python3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()
```

When I run `python3 main.py` it returns:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to s
uppress this warning.
```

From my understanding, `tkinter` comes installed with python, so there is no need to run `python3 -m pip install tkinter` (I have tried this anway) and it also doesn't show up in `pip list` for that reason. I am running Python 3.6.1 from within a virtual environment. Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @TheLizzard macOS Catalina

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58752385/tkinter-test-buttons-are-invisible-when-using-pipenv).

Comment: @TheLizzard Thanks

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried `pip install tk`?

Comment: Yes, but then I visited https://pypi.org/project/tk/ and it says it is TensorKit, which I don't think is related to tkinter?

Comment: @ManKitKwong To suggest something use the comments bellow the question. If you are sure about the solution to the problem, write an answer.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on the original post.. Try pip install pytk..That might work help

Comment: @NineDeadEyes From pypi's website: *PyTK - Python ToolKit: A thin Pythonic layer on top of TkInter GUI.* `pytk` isn't the same as `tkinter`