# Tkinter buttons are completely white Mac

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I'm creating a simple UI, my problem is that buttons are always white also if I change all their color properties...I'm new in Tkinter maybe I'm missing something.

This is the code, you can just copy and run:

```
import tkinter
tk = tkinter.Tk()


def browseFiles():
    print("Browsing...")


browseButton = tkinter.Button(
    tk, text="Browse files", command=browseFiles, fg='#03045e', bg='#caf0f8', background='#ef233c', activeforeground='blue').pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

This is a picture of result:[image]

MacOS version : `11.5.2` with`Python 3.10.0rc2`, `tcl-tk 8.6.11_1` and when I run the code this is the warning :

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.
```

Maybe I should downgrade to a python stable version ?

Comment: Does [this](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/) help?

Comment: I already read this page, in fact I downloaded python3.10 from here. But I don't understand if I need to download something and what :S. Edited version with tlc-tk version

Comment: Might as well try downgrading to stable and see if that helps.

Comment: But which one? 3.9 I don't know

Comment: Well your version has `rc2`, I think [this page](https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/) should have the latest stable versions on it. Also you should make sure that you're actually using the 3.10 version of Python to run your scripts and not whatever was included with the OS. Also I'd suggest seeing if [this page](https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/issues/1124) has any fixes that work for you.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58752385/tkinter-test-buttons-are-invisible-when-using-pipenv) is a related question with the same error message. The problem is similar too: the buttons are invisible. I suggest you read the accepted answer, and see if that works for you.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin I'm trying to figure it out but I don't have much experience and this seems to be an old problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved :

```
pip3 install tkmacosx
```

This will install some extensions that will fix the problem.
Just one thing be sure to switch interpreter, maybe you're not using the right one.
In my case it worked when I used this one [image].
Check where `tkmacosx` has been installed, you should use the same interpreter version I guess.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't solve it for me.  I've switched to Kivy as it's base install is pure python and doesn't have these issues with external libs.