# See tkinter Label on screen

Tags: tkinter, python-3.9, tkinter-text

I wanted to do my first tkinter code with python3, but when I used the code below a window opens up without any text. If somebody nows how to fix this please let me now.
I already have the latest version of tkinter and I am using the mac terminal

P.S. When I try to open the window with tkinter, this error message always pops up:

DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.

This is my code.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

myLabel1 = Label (root, text="Hello World!")
myLabel2 = Label (root, text="My name is Bugs Bunny.")

myLabel1.grid(row=0, column=0)
myLabel2.grid(row=1,column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Check the version of `tk` using `print(root.tk.call('info', 'patchlevel'))`.  Try reinstall python downloaded from python.org.

Comment: Are you on osx, and does the window come up black? It's a known problem on the Mac. Install python from python.org or homebrew and your code should work fine.

Comment: It is macOS Catalina. here is link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58752385/tkinter-test-buttons-are-invisible-when-using-pipenv