# Python installation issue

Tags: python, macos

When I type the command  `which -a python` to locate what versions of Python that it is. I get the following message:

```
$ which -a python
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin//python
/usr/bin/python
```

Now I am not sure where the "/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin//python" is being read from.

I really like to remove this reference but I can't find out where to change this.

I have tried checking the `bash_profile` but don't see any reference to the `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin//python`

I am using mac OS 10.9.5

Comment: It seems you want to remove the python installation from MAMP. Check this link, it might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4

Comment: The question is,  where is the MAAP link being read from

Comment: The question is, where is the MAMP link being read from

Comment: That path must be added somewhere into the PATH environment variable. Then, why not try searching where it has been added to PATH?

    find / -xdev -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -H "/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin//python"

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and finally fixed it.

In my .zshrc, I have this:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:$PATH
```

change it to:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
```

fixed!