# What’s the best way to remove these files yet retrieve them should an issue arise?

Tags: python, terminal, warnings, homebrew

**What’s the best way to remove these files yet retrieve them should an issue arise?** I'm trying to get Homebrew squared away and the below warnings appeared in terminal. The python.framework I'm not so concerned with, since I know I put it there. As for the other files, I do not know how they got there. They do not look familiar. **If you were in  my shoes, how would you go about getting these warning to disappear?**

```
Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or a
brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to /Library can interfere
with other software installs.

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
Unexpected dylibs:
/usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
Unexpected header files:
/usr/local/include/fakemysql.h
/usr/local/include/fakepq.h
/usr/local/include/fakesql.h
/usr/local/include/itcl.h
/usr/local/include/itcl2TclOO.h
/usr/local/include/itclDecls.h
/usr/local/include/itclInt.h
/usr/local/include/itclIntDecls.h
/usr/local/include/itclMigrate2TclCore.h
/usr/local/include/itclTclIntStubsFcn.h
/usr/local/include/mysqlStubs.h
/usr/local/include/odbcStubs.h
/usr/local/include/pqStubs.h
/usr/local/include/tcl.h
/usr/local/include/tclDecls.h
/usr/local/include/tclOO.h
/usr/local/include/tclOODecls.h
/usr/local/include/tclPlatDecls.h
/usr/local/include/tclThread.h
/usr/local/include/tclTomMath.h
/usr/local/include/tclTomMathDecls.h
/usr/local/include/tdbc.h
/usr/local/include/tdbcDecls.h
/usr/local/include/tdbcInt.h
/usr/local/include/tk.h
/usr/local/include/tkDecls.h
/usr/local/include/tkPlatDecls.h

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
Unexpected .pc files:
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tcl.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tk.pc

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.
Unexpected static libraries:
/usr/local/lib/libtclstub8.6.a
/usr/local/lib/libtkstub8.6.a
```

Comment: Do you know how these files got there in the first place?  It's probably relevant...

Comment: I am confused copy someplace else does not work?

Comment: I downloaded python, so no mystery there. As for the other files, I don't recognize them so I can not say for sure if it was something that I downloaded in the past.

Comment: Please see my post I re-edited to try and be as clear and succinct as possible. What would you do to get rid of these warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're a newbie like me and you're trying to do the Oden Project. You go through the tutorials and download Home Brew and run brew doctor yet you hit similar warnings that I have found above. This is what I did...

I created a word document and copy & pasted all the warnings so that I knew the origin of the files. Then I created a folder on my desktop called "back_up", and proceed to move the files to that folder on the desktop. See here for help on moving the files in terminal http://www.macworld.com/article/2080814/master-the-command-line-copying-and-moving-files.html

After I moved the files and noted in my word document that I moved them to a file called "back_up" on my desktop, I pruned all the symlinks as instructed. I ran brew doctor and I am now "ready to brew". I figure if it all hits the fan, I will have the original files and be able to move them back no problem.

In terms of removing the python frame work or perhaps any language you downloaded; see this - [How to uninstall Python 2.7 on a Mac OS X 10.6.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4)