# Cannot uninstall matplotlib, numpy and scipy from Python in Mac. Cannot import matplotlib from the virtualenv

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, virtualenv

Trying out a pycon tutorial on machine learning and was installing the required packages. Had some problem and accidentally installed without going into my virtualenv. Tried to uninstall matplotlib, numpy, scipy and more without any success as it gave me very long error message.

However, in python, I cannot import matlibplot as I get the following error:

> import matplotlib
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/Users/zhangsheng/Desktop/PYTHON/scikit/sk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py", line 1131, in 
>       rcParams = rc_params()
>     File "/Users/zhangsheng/Desktop/PYTHON/scikit/sk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py", line 975, in rc_params
>       return rc_params_from_file(fname, fail_on_error)
>     File "/Users/zhangsheng/Desktop/PYTHON/scikit/sk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py", line 1100, in rc_params_from_file
>       config_from_file = _rc_params_in_file(fname, fail_on_error)
>     File "/Users/zhangsheng/Desktop/PYTHON/scikit/sk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py", line 1018, in _rc_params_in_file
>       with _open_file_or_url(fname) as fd:
>     File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in **enter**
>       return self.gen.next()
>     File "/Users/zhangsheng/Desktop/PYTHON/scikit/sk/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py", line 1000, in _open_file_or_url
>       encoding = locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
>     File "/Users/zhangsheng/Desktop/PYTHON/scikit/sk/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 543, in getdefaultlocale
>       return _parse_localename(localename)
>     File "/Users/zhangsheng/Desktop/PYTHON/scikit/sk/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 475, in _parse_localename
>       raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
>   ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8

I'm quite new to stuff like this and really need help for my problem here.
Many thanks :)

I'm on a mac and I used pip to install these packages

```
pip install matplotlib
```

then uninstalling by using

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
```

Initially when i was installing in the a virtualenv I encountered a problem in installing `seaborn` after installing `matplotlib`, `scipy`, `numpy`, `scikit-learn`, `ipython`. So I uninstalled `matplotlib` and then installed `seaborn` before reinstalling `matplotlib`

**Edit:**
As I tried to uninstall those packages mentioned above, I realised that I can import `matplotlib` in my python without virtual env. However, if I was to create a virtual env using `virtualenv`and install `matplotlib`, it can't be imported in the virtual enviroment. Does anyone have a solution to my problem?

Comment: How did you install the packages? How did you try to uninstall the packages?  Please edit your post to include these details with actual commands.

Answer (score 1):

Your error has little to do with Python, but rather your shell environment. Simply add these two lines to your `~/.profile` and restart the terminal:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

If you don't have a `~/.profile`, you can safely create it - again, from the terminal:

```
vim ~/.profile
```

If you are new to vim, follow these steps:

1. Hit <kbd>ESC</kbd> (to clear the screen)
2. Hit <kbd>i</kbd> (for insert mode)
3. Copy and paste those lines
4. Hit <kbd>ESC</kbd>
5. Type the following keys, in sequence <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>

Comment: does the `~/.profile` refer to my username? How do I know if I have a profile? Many thanks :)

Comment: The `~` is a shortcut to your home directory. If you have one, the file will contain information. If its blank, that's okay too. There is a global profile that is applied to all accounts, and it is overridden if there is a local `.profile` file in the user's home directory.

Comment: I followed your instructions but I still can't uninstall those packages. Just to check if what I did was correct, type vim ~./profile (as it is, I didn't replace the profile word), follow steps 1-5 as shown above.

Comment: After you have done those steps; close the terminal and re-open it again. You need to quit it completely.  Or, you can type `source ~/.profile`

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me... Just to add, I'm using the python that comes pre-installled with the OS. Could  this be the reason that I can't uninstall? If i remember correctly, I might have used 

`sudo pip install`
 for the  installation; would this have contributed to this problem? If possible, could you elaborate on the problem on my shell environment and what might have caused this so I can have a better understand and prevent this from happening in future.

Answer (score 0):

Open Command, cmd or Dos and type this:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

then try to import again

**Edit:** if you want to uninstall you just need to delete the package from your python's site-packages directory `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages` just delete them from there.

**Edit:** by 'Them' i meant those packages that you don't need. if you couldn't find them probably it didn't install in first place.

**Edit:** that's what i get in `sit-packages` after reinstalling python:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I did that before in my virutalenv and I think it was quite successful. However, I want my python to have only the default packages and no extra packages other than `pip` and `virtualenv`. Therefore I'm wondering which are the default packages that comes with python.

Comment: @zunct10n i'm not sure too, but if you ask me, i would check the date of creation of each folder or uninstall python and delete it from root drive and reinstall it.

Comment: I tried to do what u suggested; find the date of creation, but the date of creation is not the date which I downloaded it but the date the folder was created. Regardsing uninstalling python, it is really not an option as it is a Apple supplied python which will cause my mac to brick if I really did that.

Comment: @zunct10n okay i edited my comment, maybe that help you out.

Comment: I think there's a difference for my python as I'm on a mac and the python I'm using comes pre-loaded with it by Apple. Thus I can't really reinstall python.

Comment: @zunct10n: have you try this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4    
then to install again:    
http://www.pyladies.com/blog/Get-Your-Mac-Ready-for-Python-Programming/

Comment: Haha. I have seen that before. It was from there that I read that it will break my mac if I uninstalled it.

Comment: i see... I afraid i have no any other solution for this issue. maybe try edit your question and tag your operation system. could catch attention of people expert in that area.

Comment: Thanks for your help and advice. Will do so.