# How to uninstall Python 3.4 from Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.4

I have python 2.7.9 installed by default on my mac. I then installed python 3.4.2. Later after some time, without realizing I also installed python 3.5.1. Now I have three python versions in my machine. I would like to uninstall python 3.4.1 as I have no use for it. Do you recommend doing this or should I leave it as it is? I installed everything from http://www.python.org/
Do I also need to change some path variables? And what will be my default python version?

OSX 10.11

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3819829/846641 does this answer help you? Of course you would adapt the version number.

Comment: Actually, I've got the same problem. I have something like five or even six different versions of Python installed on my Mac, although it doesn't quite disturb me.

Comment: I would recommend to completely ignore your system-level python and use [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) instead. Anaconda allows you to manage environments with different python versions, so you can have multiple versions, but always specify which one to use explicitly. This might save you a lot of trouble.