# How to install System Python 2.7 on a Mac

Tags: macos, python-2.7, pygame

I need to know **How to install System Python 2.7 on my Mac**. This is because, I unknowingly uninstalled it (I thought I was removing the Python I downloaded from [Python.org](https://python.org))

I followed [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4), and after the damage had been done, I read the comments telling me NOT TO do that.

The current reason I am wanting to install System Python 2.7 is because it is needed to install PyGame. Below is a screenshot of what I am facing when trying to install PyGame:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I recommend installing packages on OS X using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) as it keeps everything you install in one place. Allowing you to upgrade or uninstall easily and not needing to remember how or where you installed it.

Once it is installed you simply type `brew install python` in your terminal. This will install Python 2.7.10 and it will be available at `/usr/local/bin/python`.

Comment: This is good advice in general, so I'm not downvoting it, but it won't restore the system Python interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

The only supported way to restore the system Python framework on macOS is to reinstall the operating system. It is treated as a component of the core operating system, so there is no way to selectively reinstall it.

Comment: I will be willing to give this a try. Will I lose any data? (Confirming before trying)