# Uninstalling python from Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, permissions

Hi I have followed the same methods as in the link to uninstall my python 2.7, but am not able to do that even though am the super user. Getting the following error. Can someone tell me whats wrong here?

[How to uninstall python 2.7 on a mac os x 10.6.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4)

Used command:

```
Gentles-MBP:bin Gentle$ ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep '../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7' | awk '{print $9}' | tr -d @ | xargs rm
rm: 2to3-2: Permission denied
rm: 2to3-2.7: Permission denied
rm: easy_install: Permission denied
rm: easy_install-2.7: Permission denied
rm: idle: Permission denied
rm: idle2: Permission denied
rm: idle2.7: Permission denied
rm: pip: Permission denied
rm: pip2: Permission denied
rm: pip2.7: Permission denied
rm: pydoc: Permission denied
rm: pydoc2: Permission denied
rm: pydoc2.7: Permission denied
rm: python: Permission denied
rm: python-32: Permission denied
rm: python-config: Permission denied
rm: python2: Permission denied
rm: python2-32: Permission denied
rm: python2-config: Permission denied
rm: python2.7: Permission denied
rm: python2.7-32: Permission denied
rm: python2.7-config: Permission denied
rm: pythonw: Permission denied
rm: pythonw-32: Permission denied
rm: pythonw2: Permission denied
rm: pythonw2-32: Permission denied
rm: pythonw2.7: Permission denied
rm: pythonw2.7-32: Permission denied
rm: smtpd.py: Permission denied
rm: smtpd2.7.py: Permission denied
rm: smtpd2.py: Permission denied
```

EDIT

Able to go the directory:

```
Gentles-MBP:bin Gentle$ ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep '../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7'
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    68 Jan  9 17:06 2to3-2 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/2to3-2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    70 Jan  9 17:06 2to3-2.7 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/2to3-2.7
lrwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin    74 Jan  9 17:06 easy_install -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/easy_install
lrwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin    78 Jan  9 17:06 easy_install-2.7 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/easy_install-2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    66 Jan  9 17:06 idle -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/idle
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    67 Jan  9 17:06 idle2 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/idle2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    69 Jan  9 17:06 idle2.7 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/idle2.7
lrwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin    65 Jan  9 17:06 pip -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip
lrwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin    66 Jan  9 17:06 pip2 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip2
lrwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin    68 Jan  9 17:06 pip2.7 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    67 Jan  9 17:06 pydoc -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pydoc
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    68 Jan  9 17:06 pydoc2 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pydoc2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    70 Jan  9 17:06 pydoc2.7 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pydoc2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    68 Jan  9 17:06 python -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    71 Jan  9 17:06 python-32 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python-32
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    75 Jan  9 17:06 python-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    69 Jan  9 17:06 python2 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    72 Jan  9 17:06 python2-32 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2-32
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    76 Jan  9 17:06 python2-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    71 Jan  9 17:06 python2.7 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    74 Jan  9 17:06 python2.7-32 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-32
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    78 Jan  9 17:06 python2.7-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    69 Jan  9 17:06 pythonw -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    72 Jan  9 17:06 pythonw-32 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw-32
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    70 Jan  9 17:06 pythonw2 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    73 Jan  9 17:06 pythonw2-32 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2-32
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    72 Jan  9 17:06 pythonw2.7 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    75 Jan  9 17:06 pythonw2.7-32 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7-32
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    70 Jan  9 17:06 smtpd.py -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/smtpd.py
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    73 Jan  9 17:06 smtpd2.7.py -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/smtpd2.7.py
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    71 Jan  9 17:06 smtpd2.py -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/smtpd2.py
Gentles-MBP:bin Gentle$
```

Comment: Use `sudo` or something similar? Seems like you don't have permission. Check using `ls`

Comment: Am the super user Andrew

Comment: Hmm. Hard to believe with the errors. You sure try `sudo`ing and seeing if it works

Comment: I used sudo, the first 2 steps was successful

Comment: When it comes to the 3rd step, as in the question, am getting this

Comment: editted the question Andrew

Comment: Sorry man, not sure why its happening.

Comment: Perhaps you could try starting a shell with root permissions `sudo -s` and then run the command from within that.