# What is the difference between installing python from the website and using brew?

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I have a Mac with OSX 10.11.6. I used brew to install python3. It installed python 3.5.2, but I need python 3.5.1. I've been googling, but can't figure out how I would install 3.5.1 via brew. So I went to python.org and downloaded the python-3.5.1-macosx10.6.pkg. I searched for how installing python this way would differ from installing it via brew, but couldn't find any answers.

So, it is possible to brew install python 3.5.1? If not, what will it mean to install 3.5.1 via .pkg file?

Comment: Why do you specifically need 3.5.1 rather than 3.5.2? That's a difference in bug-fix release, all the functionality should be exactly the same.

Comment: Using Pycharm to run some automated tests and it's working on a coworkers machine, but not mine. We've combed through looking for differences in our set ups, and the only difference we're seeing is that he has 3.5.1 interpreter and I have 3.5.2 interpreter. So I'm doing this as a way of troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2):

> it is possible to brew install python 3.5.1?

Yes it is. See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4158763/735926).

> If not, what will it mean to install 3.5.1 via .pkg file?

The most noticeable change will be that you won’t be able to upgrade your Python installation without downloading the new version and installing it by hand (compared to `brew upgrade python3`). It’ll also be [slightly more complicated to remove](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3819829/735926) compared to `brew rm python3`.

Other than these minor differences you should have the same experience with both installations. Be sure that the `python` installed from `python-3.5.1-macosx10.6.pkg` is before Homebrew’s in your `PATH` or use its full path.