# How to delete extra pythons on Mac OS X Sierra

Tags: python, pandas

In the usr/bin folder, there are three versions of Pythons installed:  Python, Python2.6, Python2.7 (the folder names) - not sure what version is for Python folder.

My issue, originally, was that I tried to install the module 'pandas' to run a script, python keeps telling me pandas could not be found.

'pip freeze' shows me pandas is already installed.
However, I could not find pandas using python>>help>>modules.

So I suspected there are multiple pythons installed causing pip installing for one of them, but the default python is a different one.

So my questions are - 
1 Which python is the default one that comes with macOS Sierra? (I can confirm pandas currently is installed for Python, not Python2.6 or Python2.7)
2 Can I remove extra Pythons that do not have pandas? 
3 How can I find what it the default Python when I type 'Python...' and how to install pandas for that python?

Solved:
Thanks for the comments and reply.
I used "python2.7 install pip" to install pip for python2.7. Then I used command 'pip2.7 install pandas'. This way, pandas is installed for the default python. (The command 'pip install pandas' on my machine, is installing for python 2.6.)

Comment: you should first use `python --version` and `pip --version` to see which versions are being used for each, second refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/pip-dealing-with-multiple-python-versions

Comment: Please don't include screenshots of code, instead add the necessary information to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I modified my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. macOS Sierra uses Python 2.7 by default.
2. You can uninstall a version of Python as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4/3819829#3819829). However, you shouldn't need to as long as you are managing your packages and environments. If you want to maintain more control over your projects and their packages/versions, you should take a look at [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/). Virtualenv creates environments that have their own installation directories that don't share packages with other virtualenv environments. This is a very popular option many people use when managing projects.
3. You can use `pip --version` to see which version of Python you are installing a package for. You can also use `pip list` to see which packages are currently installed.

I highly recommend taking a look at virtualenv as it'll make keeping track of Python environments and their respective packages a lot easier.

Hope this helps!