# which python gives /usr/local/bin/python but python gives /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I am using OS X MAC 10.12.3. 
I have used brew to install python.
I removed python from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/ using direction in [uninstall python from /Library/Frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4).
however now when I type `$python` I get the error 
`-bash: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python: No such file or directory`
When I type `$which python`, I get `/usr/local/bin/python`.
If I type `$usr/local/bin/python`, I get the python interpreter fine.
I am baffled as to why I get an error when I type `$python` and no error when I type `$/usr/local/bin/python`. Just worried if this may cause some other problems with python later on./

Comment: Check http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47363/my-which-command-may-be-wrong-sometimes -- specifically check the values of `command -v python` and `type python` to see where bash is actually looking, and consider using `hash python` to recalculate where python should be.

Comment: Thank you very much. Had no idea about this hashing business :-). `hash python` fixed the problem.