# How to make system python to find modules installed via pip?

Tags: python, pip

I have two versions of python, `/usr/bin/python`  (version 2.7.10 in MacOS ) & `/usr/local/bin/python`(version 2.7.13 installed via `brew`).

I use `pip` (installed by `brew install python` )to install a module **`protobuf`**!

but `/usr/bin/python` cannot find the module **`protobuf`**,whereas the `/usr/local/bin/python` could find it.

how can I make the `/usr/bin/python` to find the module

**update**

@RNB
according to the installation, `sudo python get-pip.py`  I have errors like

```
:Collecting pip
  Downloading pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 640kB/s 
Collecting wheel
  Downloading wheel-0.29.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (66kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 6.3MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip, wheel
  Found existing installation: pip 8.1.2
    Uninstalling pip-8.1.2:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-8.1.2
  Rolling back uninstall of pip
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmpW2v8kJ/pip.zip/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
  .....
    File"/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 235, in _compile
    cachekey = (type(key[0]),) + key
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

**solution**

according to @RNB's advice, first clean all `pip` packages,uninstall brew python+pip,  install `pip` for sys's python by `python get-pip.py`, maybe it gives error with `wheel`, so set options `--no-setuptools`&`--no-wheel` for `python get-pip.py`,install or upgrade `setuptools` & `wheel` via `pip`.At last install `protobuf`,problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to [install pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) for `/usr/bin/python` and install **`protobuf`** via your new pip installation.

Answer (score 3):

Use the versioned Python commands in combination with the -m switch to run the appropriate copy of pip.

`python2 -m pip install SomePackage`  # default Python 2

`python2.7.10 -m pip install SomePackage`  # specifically Python 2.7.10

[check this](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html?highlight=pip#work-with-multiple-versions-of-python-installed-in-parallel)

Best practice is to use [virtualenv](http://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/#virtualenv),

If you want to install a package to a particular location using pip,
you can simply do

`pip install --install-option="--prefix=$PREFIX_PATH" package_name`

using --target option,

`pip install --target=<path> package_name`

you also need to add the `<path>` location  to `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: I want to keep OS cleaner! so I want to remove the python installed via brew.  I follow the @RNB advice to install pip for system python.  but I encounter installation errors!

Comment: follow this way to remove unwanted python versions : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3819829/4531386