# Unable to install Robotframework on Mac

Tags: python, robotframework

I had Python3.6 and Robotframework installed successfully but since python3 does not support Selenium2Library(which i needed to install)i uninstalled both python3.6 and RF, default python2.7 is there but now i am not able to install Robotframework again, it keeps giving me this error -

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/pip: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

what am i suppose to do now? where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Your system is still referring to python 3.6.
Update your PYTHONPATH to point back to python 2.7

See below answer and replace 2.7 with 3.6 in order to remove 3.6 completely

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3819829/8131798

After uninstall type python in terminal and see are you able to start python 2.7

Comment: Thank you python2.7 now started but problem with RF still there, now after doing 'pip install robotframework' its saying -  Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/robot'

Comment: Have you tried sudo?  try `sudo pip install robotframework` . Python 2.7 is system level so you need sudo to install python packages.