# Installing PyML and PyBrain with the Anaconda packages under OSX 10.10

Tags: macos, python-3.x, anaconda, pyml

Forgive me in case this too easy a question.

Background:

I installed Python 3 and Anaconda as I want to start programming Python and want to dive into machine learning. 
Unfortunately all this shell based installation thing is absolutely new to me. 
I managed to install python 3.6. and Ananconda 3.

Problem(s):

Unfortunately now I have several Python instances installed. One with Anaconda under user/anaconda and some under library/Python/

Now I need for a course to install PyML and PyBrain. I tried to it the "normal way". i.e. what is written on the webpage and as so often I get multiple errors during the installation.

Goal:

1. I'd like to have it under the Anaconda packages. Is there a way to do that?
2. If no: how can I get my other Python 3.6. installation to know the location of the Anaconda packages?

edit 12.08.17
The content of $PATH:
/Users/ak/anaconda/bin:/Users/ak/miniconda2/bin:/Users/ak/miniconda3/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Users/ak/.rbenv/shims:/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Users/ak/Library/Application Support/GoodSync:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/MacGPG2/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Users/ak/.rvm/bin

edit 12.08.17 - 2:
When I try to "conda" this libraries this happens though I started it from the unzipped, downloaded PyML:

AKs-MacBook-Pro:PyML-0.7.14 ak$ conda install -c manmadescience pyml
Fetching package metadata ...........

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

- pyml

And when I do this: conda install -c manmadescience pyml (found here https://anaconda.org/manmadescience/pyml) 
I get the same result.

Comment: What is the value of your `PATH` environment variable? To check, open Terminal and write `echo $PATH`, then paste the output into your question. In general, you should use `conda install <package-name>` to install a package for conda.

Comment: Thanks. Done. ;-)

Comment: Do you really have 3 copies of Anaconda/Miniconda installed? I would suggest you uninstall all the copies of Python on your computer that you've installed and install just one version of Anaconda, if that's what you want to use. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3819829/2449192

Comment: Aside from that, the package in the `manmadescience` channel is for `win-64` only, so you'll have to install with pip. If you have specific errors you can post about, then please post those messages.