# awscli running with python 2.7 on OS x Sierra

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, aws-sdk

I'm having an issue with my awscli version + python versions installed on my Mac.
After several tries following [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-install-macos.html) I managed to have it working, however, if i run *aws --version* I get *aws-cli/1.11.170 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/16.7.0 botocore/1.7.28*

This confused me because I thought I had just installed python 3.6, so I decided to run *which python*, and it returned */usr/bin/python*

I was still unsure and after some research I found this:

*$which python3 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3*

Now i'm totally unsure which python version is the "main" one and if it is affecting my awscli, i plan to create a restapi using aws SDK with boto3 for Python.

How can i clean my python install or simply make sure my Mac is ready to work with the aws SDK + python?

PS.: I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4) to uninstall python 2.6, 2.7 and 3.6 (currently installed on my system i suppose) but nothing really happened.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a virtual environment to create an isolated environment for all the packages in your project. You can create a virtual environment of a specific python version using the following syntax in your shell:

```
$ python3.6 -m venv env
```

One you activate the virtual environment, you can use pip to install packages into your local python instance:

```
$ source env/bin/activate
(env) $ pip install awscli
```

Whenever you plan to run your application, or install packages for the project, simply activate the virtual environment.

For more information, see the documentation for the [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) module in Python's standard library.