# How to uninstall definitely python 2.7 on MacOS

Tags: python, macos

I have install python 3.6.5 (With brew) and when I execute python command in a shell, it is always python 2.7 that come.

I have executed these command see in an [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4) but nothing work:

```
Remove the third-party Python 2.7 framework

sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7

Remove the Python 2.7 applications directory

sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Python 2.7"

Remove the symbolic links in /usr/local/bin that point to this Python version see ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep '../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7' and then run the following command to remove all the links:

cd /usr/local/bin/
ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep '../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7' | awk '{print $9}' | tr -d @ | xargs rm
```

Comment: try `python3` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's always a system Python 2.7 in macOS (`/usr/bin/python`), which you can't really remove.

Use `python3` if you want to run Python 3.

See [PEP 0394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) for details about the nomenclature.

Comment: > alias python='python3'