# Wondering how I can delete all of my python related files on Mac

Tags: python-3.x, directory, pycharm

So I was trying to install kivy, which lead me to install pip, and I went down a rabbit hole of altering directories. I am using PyCharm for the record.

I would like to remove everything python related (including all libraries like pip) from my computer, and start fresh with empty directories, so when I download pycharm again, there will be no issues.

I am using a Mac, so if any of you could let me know how to do that on a Mac, it would be greatly appreciated.

Could I just open finder, search python, and delete all of the files (there are tons) or would that be too destructive?
I hope I am making my situation clear enough, please comment any questions to clarify things.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1025189/pip-is-not-working-importerror-no-module-named-pip-internal/1026848?newreg=64574707bd3540948f5c54ec80d2b371

Force reinstalling seemed to work. Kivy and pip are now working!

Note: The issue I had was, I BELIEVE, that I had messed with my pip directory (as in where pip was located) and had tried installing too many times. Force reinstall I imagine deleted unnecessary pip files and reinstalled a cleaner version.

Answer (score 2):

**If you are familiar with the Terminal app, you can use command lines to uninstall Python from your Mac. For this, follow these steps:**

> 1. Move Python to Trash.
> 2. Open the Terminal app and type the following command line in the window: ~ alexa$ sudo rm -rf /Applications/Python\ 3.6/
> 3. It will require you to enter your administrator password to confirm the deletion.

**And for the PyCharm:**

> Just remove the ~/Library/Caches/PyCharm20 and
>   ~/Library/Preferences/PyCharm20 directories.

Or if that won't be enough:

> 1. Go to Applications > right click PyCharm > move to trash
> 2. open a terminal and run the following: find ~/Library/ -iname "*pycharm*"
> 3. verify that all of the results are in fact related to PyCharm and not something else important you need to keep. Then, remove them all
>      using the command: find ~/Library -iname "*pycharm*" -exec rm -r "{}"
>      \;

Comment: what do you mean by 'Move python to trash'? Like there are a lot of python associated files on my computer. I have the .pkg for when I downloaded python 3.6, but I have files related to python 2.7 (which I no longer use or want to have on my computer) Will that type of stuff be covered by the terminal command? Also is there some way I can share my directories with you so you can see the issues I have (any potentially try to fix them?) or would it be too much effort, making deleting the best course of action?

Comment: Here is a link to a picture, where you can see how to move python to the trash: [link](https://snag.gy/1UudHN.jpg) and to remove Python 2.7: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4

Comment: so I actually put a couple of things from /usr/bin into the trash (which after reading the first couple lines of the post you linked, made it clear that I should have not done that). Here are the files: https://snag.gy/F3wmVP.jpg. Is it safe to assume I should put them back? Also I am assuming if I right click and press 'put back' it will return them to their correct locations right?

Comment: actually I think it was /usr/local/bin **