# Uninstall all the packages installed using pip by a user on macOS High Sierra

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pip, macos-high-sierra

By mistake I installed packages in the global environment using pip. I was wondering if its a good idea to uninstall the already existing Python on the OS using the instructions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4),  and re-install it using homebrew using the instructions provided [over here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/284824/remove-and-reinstall-python-on-mac-can-i-trust-these-old-references)? Or is there any way to get rid of all packages and their dependency I installed using pip.

I'm using Python 2.7.10 on macOS High Sierra.
EDIT: Problem with a suggested approach:

As suggested by [CloC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7197281/cloc) in the comments section, I tried uninstalling all packages from global environment by typing

```
pip freeze > to_delete.txt
```

and then

```
sudo -H pip uninstall -y -r to_delete.txt
```

However I got the following error in the terminal:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-18.0-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 141, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-18.0-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/commands/uninstall.py", line 74, in run
    auto_confirm=options.yes, verbose=self.verbosity > 0,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-18.0-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 864, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset.remove(auto_confirm, verbose)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-18.0-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 221, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-18.0-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 276, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree
    raise Error, errors
Error: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/macholib/dyld.py', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-3QWFII/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/macholib/dyld.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-3QWFII/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/macholib/dyld.py'"), [...], "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-3QWFII/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/macholib'")]
```

Comment: You will not be able to uninstall the system python on Mac as it's part of the OS (at least not without turning SIP off). The system python also has several packages preinstalled (`numpy`, `matplotlib`, `six`, python bindings for the Cocoa framework etc), you won't be able to uninstall them either. You can only uninstall packages you've installed yourself. To avoid this issue in the future, always install packages with `--user` option to avoid polluting system dirs.

Comment: @hoefling Thanks ! I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 16):

You certainly should not resinstall python to have a fresh package installation.

You can easily uninstall all packages from you global environment by firstly listing them and uninstalling them:

```
pip freeze > to_delete.txt
```

And then:

```
pip uninstall -y -r to_delete.txt
```

If you do not want to uninstall all of them, you can delete the lines you want to keep in the `to_delete.txt` file created in the first step.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, but I think your approach will delete all packages, including the pre-insatlled ones. I only want to delete the packages I installed using pip.

Comment: `pip freeze` outputs packages installed via `pip`. System-level packages such as `pip` itself, or `wheel` and `setuptools` are skipped. If you have any doubts, you can still run `pip freeze --user` to outputs packages installed in user-site only.

Comment: Thanks again, I tried but got some errors which I have added in the question. Please have a look when you are free.

Comment: Right, since you are not in a virtual env, you may need to run the commands listed using `sudo` : `sudo pip freeze > to_delete.txt` and `sudo pip uninstall -y -r to_delete.txt`

Comment: Yup, I did try using `sudo pip freeze > to_delete.txt`  and got the output I showed in the question.

Comment: And have you tried adding the `-H` flag parameter as recommended by the error message? `sudo -H pip ...`

Comment: Nope, got errors again. I have updated it in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180329/discussion-between-cloc-and-smit-kamal).

Answer (score 3):

> is there any way to get rid of all packages and their dependency I installed using pip.

If you would install the packages with `--user` option, the solution would be simple: list all user-installed packages and uninstall them in batch:

```
$ pip list --format=freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

However, since you have installed the packages system wide (using `sudo`), the command will get somewhat hairy. MacOS ships some packages as part of the system; these are located under `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python`. You can neither uninstall those nor install additional packages in the system dir. Every package you install via `sudo pip install` lands under `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` to ensure the OS files are not modified or removed. The solution would thus be:

1. List all packages locatable by `pip`
2. Filter out those installed under `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`
3. Uninstall them by name

Example in `bash`:

```
$ pip list --format=freeze | cut -d= -f1 | \
  xargs -I {} bash -c 'pip show {} | ( grep -q "Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages" && echo {} )' | \
  xargs pip uninstall -y
```

### Caution

This will uninstall ALL system packages that are not preinstalled with MacOS! This includes `pip` itself, if you installed it system wide, e.g. via `sudo easy_install pip`. Also, there might be packages that were installed by other tools, for example Virtualbox installs python bindings in a package called `vboxapi` - this would be also uninstalled. It might be better to just list the package names:

```
$ pip list --format=freeze | cut -d= -f1 | \
  xargs -I {} bash -c 'pip show {} | ( grep -q "Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages" && echo {} )'
```

analyze the results and uninstall selected packages in a separate command.

Answer (score 2):

I know my answer is late but it may help to someone.

**Windows environment**:

```
pip freeze > unins && pip uninstall -y -r unins && del unins
```

**Linux environemnt**:

```
pip freeze > unins && pip uninstall -y -r unins && rm unins
```

Using the above commands, you can ***delete all the packages*** which you installed using `pip` command.