# Pipenv trouble on MacOS "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable"

Tags: python, macos, pipenv

I'm starting to try and get a working pipenv, however on my Mac, it is appears that my Python enviroment is a little screwed. I removed OS X python following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4) , and installed both python2.7 and python3.7 using brew. But now when trying to use pipenv(2.7) to create a virtualenv, and pipfile, I keep getting an error about python 3.7, when locking pacakges:

```
$ pipenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python install pynetbox ipaddress
Virtualenv already exists!
Removing existing virtualenv...
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /Users/daniel/scripts/netbox/Pipfile

...

adding ipaddress to Pipfile's [packages]...
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
c/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 250, in actually_resolve_deps
    req = Requirement.from_line(dep)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.7.1/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/requirementslib/models/requirements.py", line 704, in from_line
    line, extras = _strip_extras(line)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
/usr/local/Cellar/pipenv/2018.7.1/libexec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/_compat.py:113: ResourceWarning: Implicitly cleaning up <TemporaryDirectory '/var/folders/pc/hlxw3whn3cl1x3h45ll2m8gw0000gs/T/pipenv-TYWa8Y-requirements'>
  warnings.warn(warn_message, ResourceWarning)
```

I have reinstalled PIP, and python a few times, and no luck. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Im sure by python is probably just in some bad state :(

Answer (score 27):

This is a bug in pipenv caused by using it alongside the newest version of pip (18.1): https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/2924.  You need to downgrade pip — both inside and outside the pipenv environment — to version 18.0 in order for pipenv to work.

Comment: > both inside *and outside* the pipenv environment

Answer (score 21):

Actual commands to do as the answer by @jwodder.

Run the following commands on the root directory.

```
pip install pipenv
```

Then

```
pipenv run pip install pip==18.0
```

Then

```
pipenv install
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed steps for the next person that finds this!

Comment: Just wanted to point out that this "work around" did not work for me

Comment: @fccoelho did you execute this in the root directory??

Comment: @EsirKings  It's actually in my case it is part of a Dockerfile, So it is run as root to update the global pip. actually pip install pip==18.0 and after that the pipenv command above inside the venv

Comment: I get `TypeError: resolve_deps() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verbose'` after running the 3rd command `pipenv install`

Comment: fixed that by running `pip install pip==18.0` _outside_ of a pipenv

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers were correct at the time, but the issue seems to have been fixed in the latest version of `pipenv`. Updating it fixed it for me:

```sh
pip3 install --upgrade pipenv
```

This allows you to run the latest versions of both `pip` and `pipenv` without problems