# Not able to install packages or upgrade pip with Heroku

Tags: django, heroku, pip

I'm using GitHub and Heroku to run my Django app.  The app works as expected locally but I'm running into problems when pushing (via GitHub) it up to Heroku.  I think I boiled it down to something not working with requirements.txt or the general pip set up.  Specifically, I've been trying to install Django-Bootstrap4.  It is in the requirements file.

I definitely don't understand this process and I very well might not even be asking the right questions. But I've tried following all of the documentation found here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip.

When I'm in the virtual environment locally, everything looks fine.  Then after doing:

```
> heroku login
> heroku run pip install django-bootstrap4 (or pip or pandas)
```

It seems to install, but then running:

```
> heroku run pip list
```

nothing has changed.  TIA

requirements.txt

```
certifi==2018.8.24
chardet==3.0.4
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.1.2
django-bootstrap4==0.0.7
django-heroku==0.3.1
django-registration-redux==2.5
gunicorn==19.9.0
idna==2.7
psycopg2==2.7.5
pytz==2018.5
requests==2.19.1
urllib3==1.23
whitenoise==4.1
```

Pipfile

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.6"
```

Adding Log:

```
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915341+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915343+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915345+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915346+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915347+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915349+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915350+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915351+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915352+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915354+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915355+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915356+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915357+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915358+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915359+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915360+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app/wsgi.py", line 7, in <module>
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915362+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915363+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915364+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915365+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915366+00:00 app[web.1]: apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915367+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915368+00:00 app[web.1]: app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915369+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915370+00:00 app[web.1]: module = import_module(entry)
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915372+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915373+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915426+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrap4'
2018-11-06T02:34:49.915794+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-06 02:34:49 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919437+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-06 02:34:49 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919439+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919441+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919443+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919444+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919446+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919447+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919448+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919450+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919451+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919453+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919454+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919456+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919458+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919459+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919461+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919462+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app/wsgi.py", line 7, in <module>
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919464+00:00 app[web.1]: application = get_wsgi_application()
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919465+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919467+00:00 app[web.1]: django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919469+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919470+00:00 app[web.1]: apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919472+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919473+00:00 app[web.1]: app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919474+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919476+00:00 app[web.1]: module = import_module(entry)
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919477+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919479+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2018-11-06T02:34:49.919480+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bootstrap4'
2018-11-06T02:34:49.920093+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-06 02:34:49 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2018-11-06T02:34:50.079130+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-06 02:34:50 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2018-11-06T02:34:50.079281+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-11-06 02:34:50 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Comment: Can you provide more info on what makes you think "omething not working with requirements.txt or the general pip set up"? A log when you deploy is great

Comment: Added the log as well as requirements.txt and Pipfile.

Answer (score 3):

`heroku run` creates an one-off Dyno and runs your command in it, your changes wouldn't be persisted.

You actually don't need to `pip install` yourself. [Doc here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip)

> To specify Python package dependencies on Heroku via pip, add a pip
>   requirements file named requirements.txt to the root of your
>   repository.

Answer (score 3):

First, run `pip install django-bootstrap4`

Secondly, run `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Then add and commit - `git add requirements.txt && git commit -m 'added django-bootstrap4 && git push heroku master`

This will install the package in your Heroku app.

Comment: @Pawel I updated my answer to include the first step, which is running ```pip install django-bootstrap4``` in your terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52821649/4490230

Something about an issue running the latest version of pipenv with pip.  Specifically, I had to downgrade not only in the virtual environment but the root as well.