# "No module named torch" on Heroku

Tags: pytorch

I installed torch with this to Heroku:

https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.3.1%2Bcpu-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl

But in Heroku, it says "No module named 'torch'.

My requirements.txt:

```
autopep8==1.4.3
certifi==2020.6.20
cffi==1.14.0
click==7.1.2
colorama==0.4.1
cryptography==2.9.2
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.8
Flask-Limiter==1.3.1
idna==2.10
isort==4.3.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
limits==1.5.1
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mccabe==0.6.1
numpy==1.18.5
pandas==1.1.0
pycodestyle==2.4.0
pycparser==2.20
PyJWT==1.7.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2020.1
six==1.15.0
https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.3.1%2Bcpu-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
Werkzeug==1.0.1
wincertstore==0.2
```

Comment: Can you run command `pip freeze` to see if it is really installed?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: @404pio Its installing other packages and not recognizing my requirements.txt

Comment: @FerhatPektas do you have any logs of installing packages?

Comment: @404pio I am writing `heroku run pip install -r requirements.txt` but it says  Error: remote requirements.txt not found in git remotes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53165167/1615070

Comment: @404pio Not working. It's not recognizing

Comment: When you run `heroku` command, it looks for files on heroku servers. But requirements.txt is not present there. To upload it, common workflow is to commit and push your files to `heroku` git remote as I linked.

Comment: @404pio Yeah, I know... But it's just not working. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Why is it not working?

Comment: @404pio that was a gunicorn error. I fixed it