# Unable to uninstall python 2.7 in mac os

Tags: python, macos, terminal, command, uninstallation

I have python 2.7 installed on my macbook pro in /usr/bin. When I do ls python*  I see these files: python          python-config       python2.7       python2.7-config    pythonw         pythonw2.7.

I want to delete them but I can't find a way to do it, I've tried sudo rm -rf  and other things but nothing seems to work.

When I do sudo rm -rf I get this:

rm: python: Operation not permitted,

and when I do  sudo rm python I get this

override rwxr-xr-x  root/wheel restricted,compressed for python?

I want to delete python entirely from my system , can someone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to uninstall Python 2.7 on a Mac OS X 10.6.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4)

Comment: Who do you want to remove python 2.7.

Answer (score -1):

Do not remove python 2.7 from your Mac computer. As you have seen you probably can't anyway. The Mac uses python and the files are protected to be sure they are not removed.

If you want to run another version of python install it and set up virtual environments.

Answer (score -1):

Referenced [here](https://gist.github.com/scottvrosenthal/1c0b602b6f551939f0b1)

```sh
# sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework
sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7
sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Python 2.7"
```

```sh
cd /usr/local/bin && \
sudo ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep '../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7' | awk '{print $9}' | xargs rm
```

Answer (score -3):

Lol can't believe no one has said this:

Boot into recovery, turn off SIP:
**csrutil disable**
restart,
open terminal
**cd /usr/bin**
then
**sudo chmod -R 777 ./**
try it again
**$ python --version**
you should no longer see it