# Clean up MacOS Python installation

Tags: python, macos

When I try to check Python version installed on my MacOS 10.14.5 machine, instead of the version I get the following output:

```
$ python -v
# installing zipimport hook
import zipimport # builtin
# installed zipimport hook
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.py
import site # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py
import os # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.pyc
import errno # builtin
import posix # builtin
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py
import posixpath # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/stat.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/stat.py
import stat # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/stat.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py
import genericpath # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/genericpath.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/warnings.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/warnings.py
import warnings # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/warnings.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/linecache.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/linecache.py
import linecache # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/linecache.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/types.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/types.py
import types # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/types.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py
import UserDict # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py
import _abcoll # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/abc.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/abc.py
import abc # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/abc.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.py
import _weakrefset # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyc
import _weakref # builtin
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py
import copy_reg # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/traceback.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/traceback.py
import traceback # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/traceback.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py
import sysconfig # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py
import re # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py
import sre_compile # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.pyc
import _sre # builtin
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py
import sre_parse # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py
import sre_constants # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.pyc
dlopen("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_locale.so", 2);
import _locale # dynamically loaded from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_locale.so
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.py
import _sysconfigdata # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_osx_support.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_osx_support.py
import _osx_support # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_osx_support.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/new.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/new.py
import new # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/new.pyc
import encodings # directory /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py
import encodings # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/codecs.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/codecs.py
import codecs # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/codecs.pyc
import _codecs # builtin
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.py
import encodings.aliases # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.pyc
# /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc matches /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py
import encodings.utf_8 # precompiled from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc
Python 2.7.16 (v2.7.16:413a49145e, Mar  2 2019, 14:32:10) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
dlopen("/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so", 2);
import readline # dynamically loaded from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so
>>>
```

I guess this has something to do with the fact that, as a developer, I have installed a lot of different versions of Python with different installers (HomeBrew, PKG installer, etc) so I may have messed up my installation, not to mention that there is a version installed in MacOS already.

How can I clean that up and reinstall Python so that `python -v` just shows me the version?

Note that I tried following several procedures like this one: [How to uninstall Python 2.7 on a Mac OS X 10.6.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4/)
But so far it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> so that `python -v` just shows me the version?

That isn't the command to show the version. That is to start in *verbose mode*.

You want `python -V`

Comment: Or `python --version`.

Comment: Of course! Super intuitive... and super dumb of me not to have checked that. Thanks a lot