# mac os Catalina 10.15.2 built in python version

Tags: python, macos-catalina

How could I check what is the built in python version for mac os Catalina 10.15.2.

Have a problem with "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/". Think to remove this version and reinstall. Read this post, [How to uninstall Python 2.7 on a Mac OS X 10.6.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4)  one post reminds  not to remove Mac built in python.

I have multiple versions of python managed by pyenv.

Just wonder where could I check Mac Catalina 10.15 built in python version?

Comment: Type `python --version` in a Terminal window.

Comment: Just edited to make my question more clear. This command only give the current global python version.

Answer (score -1):

```
~$ xcrun python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Sep  5 2019, 17:14:41) 
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.8)] on darwin
```

Comment: Python 3 is not the built-in Python version in Mac OS Catalina.