# Move from python 2 to python 3 on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, migrating

I have both python 2.7.16 and python 3.7.3 on my Macbook air.
I don't use python 2.7.16 so I want to remove it, but I understood that this could break my Mac.
I am frustrated from using `python3` and `pip3` instead of `python` and `pip` is there a way to make all of the python3 commands to be accessed by using `python` (without 3) instead of python 2 and make python 2 be accessible by using `python2`?
tnx ahead

Comment: If you work with virtual environments, you'll need python3 to create the venv, but after you have sourced it, you can just use python and pip from within it. I think this is a safer option than changing any of the defaults on your mac, and it will make your projects more reproducible.

Comment: You could also add `alias python=python3` to your `.zshenv` :)

Comment: The safest option is to use a virtual environment. Then you can use everything in this virtual environment and it doesn't mess up with other dependencies. 
Check [python virtual env](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/)

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4

Answer (score 0):

```
(base) shrub$ /usr/bin/py
pydoc             python            python2.7         pythonw
pydoc2.7          python-config     python2.7-config  pythonw2.7
```

Looking in /usr/bin there is a python executable (which when run opens a shell with python3) and a python2.7 executable (which when run opens a shell with python2).

```
(base) shrub$ python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug 13 2019, 15:17:50)
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

(base) shrub$ python2.7
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb 22 2019, 21:55:15)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.37.14)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Running python scripts with python (python hello.py for example) should default to python3 and running scripts with python2.7 (python2.7 hello.py for example) will run them with python2.

Also there is a script called 2to3 which can help you with converting your python2 code to python3 :)
https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/2to3.html