# Can't run packages installed with pip3 on Mac (permission denied)

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, permissions, pip

I currently have a package I'd like to run, Psiturk, in the command line on my Mac (Catalina 10.15.4). This package was installed with pip3. I can't recall how I installed pip3. I installed python3 with Homebrew. `brew info python` tells me that pip3 installs packages into the site-package directory `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`.

I had an issue where `psiturk` was not found as a command. I had to add the above site-package directory to my PATH variable. Once I did that, I was able to have `psiturk` be recognized as a valid executable in my command line.

Now, when I run `psiturk`, I receive a permissions error `[Errno 13]`. I attempted to reinstall `psiturk` through `pip3 install psiturk --user` and now I receive another permission error:

`ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/twizzler/Library/Python/3.7'`

And now, after running that command and receiving that error, `psiturk` is not listed as a package under `pip3 list`. At this point, I'm convinced I should reinstall python on my Mac properly with virtualenv.

Other useful info: I have three pythons: `/usr/bin/python`, `usr/bin/python2`, `usr/bin/python3`. Running just `pip` gives me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.main'`. `which pip3` returns `/usr/local/bin/pip3`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3819829/13314450

Then reinstall python with brew.

You can also try `brew doctor`