# How do I remove python 3.8 when i have both python 3.7 and 3.8 installed on MacOS?

Tags: python-3.x, macos

I have a really messy python installation on my mac, need some help.

I installed python3 with Homebrew and it showed that
`python 3.7.8 is already installed and up-to-date`

But when I run python3 on my terminal, i see,

```
Python 3.8.3 (default, May 27 2020, 20:53:40)
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

And now i cant install any modules with pip3, it shows,

```
File "/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/pip3", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
```

I would like to remove python 3.8 completely and use 3.7 instead, what should I do?

Comment: Use homebrew to manage your thirdparty tools and libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4/3819829#3819829)

In the link there is solution about deleting 2.8. I guess deleting python versions does not change version to version. Check that link.