# Can I uninstall python2 from macos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, terminal

My mac has python3 and python2 installed by default.

Before now, only python3 and pip3 commands were working on the macOS terminal. But when I upgraded my pip `pip3 install --upgrade pip`, my pip command works as well, and when I type `python --version` it shows 2.7.16. Although I still have python3 installed, I don't like having python2. Can I uninstall python2 or is it just not possible?

Keep in mind that the `python --version` command showed an error before I upgraded pip

Comment: ["Future versions of macOS won’t include scripting language runtimes by default"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/macos-release-notes/macos-catalina-10_15-release-notes), so you could just wait for a few releases.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4 read this see if it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

If Python 2 was installed onto your Mac by default, do NOT try to remove it as it is not possible, and could break your entire operating system.

Answer (score 0):

As @GavinWong said, do not try to remove Python 2 from your Mac. Some of the scripts used by the operating system are written in Python 2 and hence Python 2 must be available for Mac to fubtion properly.