# Error returned when importing geojson using Python 3.6.8

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, geojson, macos-catalina

I am using macOS Catalina (Version 10.15.1). I currently have Python 3.6.8 installed and am using that shell to run my scripts. I installed `geojson` using `pip install geojson`. It installed to the following location:

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (2.5.0)`

When I tried to do `import geojson` in my python script, the following error was returned:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geojson’`

I thought that maybe this is because `geojson` is installed to the 2.7 version of Python, so perhaps I need to remove 2.7 and then re-install geojson, and hopefully geojson will be installed to my 3.6 version/folder... Also to be clear, I did install Python 2.7 awhile back, so I'm not talking about the system supplied Python. I followed [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3819829/12304196) to uninstall Python 2.7. Now, when I go to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions`, I only have 3.6, so it seems like this worked as expected.

When I ran `pip install geojson` again, the following message was returned:
`Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeaoble Collecting geojson Using caoNched geojson-2.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB) Installing collected packages: geojson SuccessfuloNly installed geojson-2.5.0`

Finally, when I ran `import geojson` in my script again, I got the same `ModuleNotFound` error. I’m really not sure what to do next here… I also struggled awhile back to install and use `geopandas` and eventually gave up because I was going over my head trying to navigate Mac’s terminal and package locations, and I didn’t want to permanently do any damage to my OS. I'm wondering if the problem was similarly related to installing packages to the earlier Python version, and running the later version of Python in the shell, and not being able to access those installed packages because they are in a different location. Is this actually the issue here?

Answer (score 2):

Try using:
'''
pip3 install geojson
'''