# How to uninstall Python 3.6 safely and let 3.9 installed on Mac big sur?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, crash, python-idle, macos-big-sur

Recently my Mac got updated to big sur and pycharm and idle stopped working : both crash. I have read Google but want a sure shot way to uninstall 3.6 and have only 3.9. Also will the application programs I created with 3.6 will get destroyed on removing 3.6?

I won’t like to reinstall Mac or something just need a working procedure for the same. My Mac has many apps loaded on it

Hoping for early reply

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to uninstall Python 2.7 on a Mac OS X 10.6.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4)

Comment: Do I follow the upper part and delete python or follow the second section which says don’t delete anything?

Comment: Don't know. I watch the PyCharm tag and use Windows for the most part. If this were a Windows post I'd know exactly what to do. But this being a MacOS post I linked you to the most upvoted thread on the subject, it's the best I can do. Read it carefully and try using search to get a few 2nd opinions. Hopefully, someone more knowledgeable will answer. You may also want to try and take a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/ that's probably where all the Mac users hangout.

Comment: Use virtual environments (e.g. conda, which it is fully supported also in PyCharm). So you can have parallel versions, and for every project, you can have a different environment (and different python version). Updates should not crash your python (it never did to me). Maybe you are forgetting some "fix" you tried which really broke things?

Comment: BTW PyCharm is written in Java/Kotlin so you should have no crash. I think you should ask about the crashes on apple.SE. I doubt they are related to Python.

Comment: Seems like Apple needs to address this so opened a thread there. Anybody interested here's the Link https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/420854/how-to-uninstall-python-3-6-safely-and-let-3-9-remain-installed-on-my-mac-big-su. Thanks all

Comment: Will mark this resolved when Apple provides solution