# How to add Python Interpreter to PyCharm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pycharm, pythoninterpreter

I followed a lot suggestions to add the interpreter to PyCharm, but they're simply not working. I want to figure out what the exact problem is here.

First, it said no interpreter is found, so I tried using Python 3.10 in Anaconda. But it seems "pip install packages" don't get used for Anaconda's Python. So, I used Terminal to get a different Python PATH: `open -e .bash_profile` and to see which python versions
I have using `python -v`, `python3 -v`, `which python`, `which python3`. So, I wanted to input `/usr/local/bin/python3` or `/usr/bin/python` for the interpreter path.

The problem is that I can't add them at all... "Add Python Interpreter" doesn't let me click 'ok'.

[Need to Add Python Interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49q5X.png)

I watched lots of YouTube tutorials and went through relevant websites for suggestions, but nothing works. I even got rid of Python from all the folders manually (except the ones that didn't allow me to trash) and using Terminal as instructed ([How to uninstall Python 2.7 on a Mac OS X 10.6.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4/68044836)): `sudo rm -rf Python`, `sudo rm -rf "/Applications/Python 2.7"`,

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep '../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7' | awk '{print $9}' | tr -d @ | xargs rm
```

Then, I tried reinstalling them using pip install python3. It says Python 3.9 already exists in some Frameworks location, and I am unsure where to go about from now since nothing seems to be working.

Any suggestions would be great. Thank you.

I'm new to programming and Stack Overflow (came here a couple of times for solutions but only recently signed up and posted), so if my questions should be posed another way, please let me know.

Comment: Did a little red error-popup not appear on your screen (from the screenshotted image) when you selected /usr/bin as the location? 'location' there means the folder to create the project's virtualenv in, *not* the interpreter's location. I get an error, "Environment location directory is not empty", when trying to make a virtualenv in /usr/bin. Choose an empty folder to place your project environment in.

Comment: @kcsquared I didn't get the error pop-up, so I didn't know what went wrong for a long time. Glad to know what the actual problem was. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interface shown in your image is for creating a new python environment (i.e. virtual environment). It sounds like you want to use an existing environment. So click on the `Existing environment` radia button in your image instead of `New Environment`. Then navigate to the `python` executable you want.

The prompts might make more sense to you if you click `System Interpreter` on the left hand side, but that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: This works! Thank you so much! I previously thought I can only use the Existing environment once I make a New environment on Pycharm since a lot of Python Interpreter tutorials on YouTube started with the New environment. But glad to know it doesn't work that way.

Comment: @blackbird7 Glad to help! (If an answer is helpful to you, please consider giving an upvote and 'accepting' an answer if it solves your problem)