# Delete pyenv remains

Tags: python, pycharm, pyenv

After some time I got completely confused with Python configuration on my Mac because I couldn't handle Homebrew and pyenv with lack of knowledge. This led me to the failed work of a python IDE Pycharm. Uninstalling pyenv and reinstalling Python (v.3.11) fixed the problem somehow but strange objects stayed on my Mac - may I simply delete them?

- after running
  `find / -perm +111 -type f -iname "python" 2>/dev/null`
- I found following strange artefacts:

`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`

`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`

`/System/Volumes/Data/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`

`/System/Volumes/Data/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`

`/System/Volumes/Data/Users/admin/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/Python`

`/System/Volumes/Data/Users/admin/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`

`/Users/admin/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/Python`

`/Users/admin/.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`

These objects don't actually prevent the normal work of IDE but I would like to clean the system.

Comment: Honestly, you should not worry about this.  Many packages leave remnants that do not affect operation.  That's especially true for the `/Library` and `/System` folders.  You don't know what other apps might be using them.

Comment: echoing but reinforcing Tim's comment - **do not delete your system python** -mac OS relies on python. Generally, don't mess with `/System` - you could end up bricking your computer. see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4. but it's definitely worth investing the time to learn to use an environment manager like venv or conda.

Comment: Dear all, you could not imagine how supportive are your help for me because I’m completely frustrated staying alone in front of the ocean of uncertainty! Could you help to understand - is such a path as ‘blabla - pyenv - blabla - 3.6.8 - blabla - 3.11’ in remnants the real path for my current working 3.11 python?