# find_namespace: directive is unsupported on Python < 3.3

Tags: python, terminal, pip

There's much more to the problem than the title suggests, so I'm just going to start from the beginning.

I'm trying to install google.colab, and when I type `pip3 install google.colab`, I get the following error:
`python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully. │ exit code: 1`

I googled this error and I followed all the instructions on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991403/pip-install-unroll-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1) post, which matches up with the advice on most other posts and websites, however for the first few bits of the instructions, it says I already have those things installed. I finally got around to `easy_install -U setuptools`, it gives me the error in the title, `find_namespace: directive is unsupported on Python < 3.3`.

I've double checked and I have python 3.11 installed. I can't uninstall python 2.7 entirely, but I followed the instructions on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819449/how-to-uninstall-python-2-7-on-a-mac-os-x-10-6-4) post.

How do I remedy this? I've googled stuff about namespaces, and it went over my head. I'm fairly new to python.

Comment: Do not use `pip3 command ...`. Use `path/to/python3.11 -m pip command ...` instead. https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: I tried this, and I still got the same error